# Moodle-progress bar

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

In moodle,I could see the default course progress for the courses in the moodle on the front end. But when tried to show the progress like 10% completed when chapter1 gets completed, 20% completed when chapter2 gets completed and so on. I could not find any module or could not figure out how to modify the code.

In other words:1. How to track the progress of course completion based on course subsections completion? Because default tracking based on courses based only.2. It is possible to track the courses without (refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUqwT.png) ticking the course completion checkbox?3. Based on the URL viewing of course sections, is it possible to track the course progress?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes track specific page views and interactions via the `mdl_logstore_standard_log` table. Different modules/activities in Moodle log different types/amounts of data, but views of typical course topics/sections are usually logged regardless of completion.

For example, imagine a course with id=10 where you visit section/topic 3. The URL usually looks something like this: `<yourdomain>/course/view.php?id=10&section=3`

In this case, the view should be logged in mdl_logstore_standard_log with an eventname value of `\core\event\course_viewed`. The course id should be in the courseid column and the section viewed should be in the "other" column, although that data is an array stored with PHP serialization, so it's helpful to use unserialize and array parsing functions to get the "3" quickly if needed.

Again, keep in mind different activities/modules log data differently - for example, an assignment activity is logged differently - but hope this helps you find what you need. Good luck!